# Failing RegistrationsController test with User model having one related Address model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, rspec2

I'm trying to test the create method of an overriden Devise controller to ensure that when my registration form is submitted, my user gets created in the database with an address associated.
Actually using the form to submit data works fine.

Now when firing the test I get :

```
Failure/Error: post :create, :user => {
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant User::Address
```

Here is the code for the different actors :

The user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     

  has_many :products, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shops

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable


  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,       :remember_me, :address_attributes

end
```

Then the Address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :address

end
```

The RegistrationsController :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.build_address
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

I'm overriding the new method to create a related address

And finally the test :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RegistrationsController do

  render_views

  describe "the registration process" do

    before do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end

    it "creates a new user" do
      lambda do
        post :create, :user => {
            :email => 'user@test.com',
            :password => 'somepassword',
            :password_confirmation => 'somepassword',
            :address_attributes => {
              :address => 'an address'
            }
        }
      end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

  end


end
```

Same thing happen if I write a test using Capybara filling the form instead of posting the hash.

It seems like it doesn't recognizes ActiveRecord relationships in test environment.
I'm quite new to rails testing world so it might be something quite straightforward, but I've already been spending a lot of time trying to figure out what's going on.

Thanks for helping